# Best Practice for Adding Color Hover Effect

Tags: html, css

Sorry for being a CSS noob but I was hoping I could ask the best way to add a CSS hover effect for changing color on longer classes.

For example

```
    header.header-div.top-nav1.nav-div.nav-without-login-div.ullist-inline li .btn- 
       custom-rounded.btn-login {
       background: #fff !important;
       color: #ff771e  !important;
       border: 1px solid #ff771e  !important;
       text-transform: initial;
    }
```

Normally when doing smaller project I would just do

`:hover {}`

Then change the background color or something but I was hoping to ask experienced front end devs what they would do.

Comment: `:hover` is a pseudo-class affiliated with your selector - so it doesn't matter how long the selector (class) is.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti 
Thank you for the comment. 
So it would be okay (best practice) to re-write the code and add hover to the end so the color of the text changes ?

Comment: @Sfili_81
Yes its a big group project and I dont think many of us understand CSS well

Comment: If you wanted to could add on an `id` to the element rather than changing the class. You could add the `:hover` to the `id`. **But** remember classes are reused and ids are meant to be used in one place.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti it may not matter, but since they are asking for best practices, I'd suggest organizing the CSS code in a cleaner and more maintainable way. Usually when you use classes (or ids) you can omit all the verbose selection of the previous elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :hover on any selector, no matter how long it is.

Answer (score 0):

firstly if you want to add a hover on an element you do not need to start writing classes from the start like you have written around 7-10 classes.
instead give it an id and keep your css concise and easy to read for the other devs!

and as told before by a few it doesn't matter how long your selector is just put `:hover{}`  at the end and you will be good to go but since you asked so yeah i would rather give it an id or incase you aren't comfortable with using id then give it a unique class name and just use that as a selector instead of this long syntax!

Hope this was helpful!